# How to protect tftp server on pc?

Tags: firewall, tftp

I run ubuntu, and I've installed tftp-hpa on my system. I've read that I need to secure my network when I have tftp. Here what I'm talking about and I would like to know the steps to do what they recommend.
thanks.
[openwrt tftp](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/troubleshooting/tftpserver)

> If your computer is also used as a desktop computer for general purpose or for other purpose than build/compile, then make sure TFTP-client & TFTP-server, are both placed behind a firewall (frwl) system or rules1, 2. Firewall rules should be:

```
    (frwl rule # 1) allow TFTP traffic (UDP 69) only when connections originate from a local LAN ip.address range and also end in the local LAN ip.address range
    (frwl rule # 2) TFTP traffic is Not-Allowed when it is from/to 127.0.0.1 or lo
    (frwl rule # 3) TFTP traffic is Not-Allowed when originated from Internet-ip-address (aka: NON private-LAN ip-address ranges)
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting to clarify what exactly is quoted. Quoted lines start with `>`. If possible, also provide a link to where you’re quoting from so we can judge the context.

Comment: The site you link to is specific to OpenWrt recovery. It is not a general TFTP server guide.

Comment: Yes but about the protection and allow only lan side it is not related to OpenWrt.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you are looking at is not about operating a TFTP server. It is about operating a temporary TFTP server to recover OpenWrt on a router, while possibly being directly connected to the internet at the same time. It is not very helpful/applicable otherwise for multiple reasons:

1. A server on the local network already is protected by the router firewall; unless you explicitly allow remote traffic in, it’s not happening
2. You wouldn’t run a TFTP server with write access enabled except in specific circumstances
3. You wouldn’t run a low-quality TFTP server with potential or even known vulnerabilities

Just run the *tftp-hpa* `in.tftpd` with `--secure` and proper filesystem permissions (only read) and you’re good.